# How to stop a subprocess? (Python)

Tags: python, subprocess

I have tried both terminate() and kill() but both have failed to stop a subprocess I start in my python code.

Is there any other way?

On Windows with Python 2.7

I have also tried the following with no results...

```
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

and

```
import ctypes
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, theprocess.pid)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
```

Comment: Is this subprocess a shell script that starts other processes? I have a similar issue documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102535/python-how-to-determine-subprocess-children-have-all-finished-running

Comment: How are you starting it?

Comment: It is being started with subprocess.Popen

Comment: Are you using `shell=True` in the call to `subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: Using TerminateProcess is bad. You sure that the process is still running when you try to kill it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the os.system('taskkill') here:http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Try using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), or another way to remotely kill the process itself (psutil is cross platform so the code is nicer):

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.terminate()  #or p.kill()
```

Code taken from [How to terminate process from Python using pid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid).

Note that if using `shell=True`, the PID is of the shell and not any process it spawned. To kill a subprocess with `shell=True` you may look at [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)