# How to terminate process from Python using pid?

Tags: python, linux, process, terminal

I'm trying to write some short script in python which would start another python code in subprocess if is not already started else terminate terminal & app (Linux).

So it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen

text_file = open(".proc", "rb")
dat = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

def do(dat):

    text_file = open(".proc", "w")
    p = None

    if dat == "x" :

        p = Popen('python StripCore.py', shell=True)
        text_file.write( str( p.pid ) )

    else :
        text_file.write( "x" )

        p = # Assign process by pid / pid from int( dat )
        p.terminate()

    text_file.close()

do( dat )
```

Have problem of lacking knowledge to name proces by pid which app reads from file *".proc"*.
The other problem is that interpreter says that string named *dat* is not equal to *"x"* ??? What I've missed ?

Comment: Why are you passing `shell=True`? AFAIK it isn't needed in your use case. Note also that when using `shell=True` the pid returned by `p.pid` is *not* the pid of the python process, but the pid of the shell spawned to execute this process.

Comment: +1 for your comment, but I consider it as appropriate because I need to close terminal as well.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Using the awesome [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library it's pretty simple:

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.terminate()  #or p.kill()
```

If you don't want to install a new library, you can use the `os` module:

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL
```

See also the [`os.kill` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill).

---

If you are interested in starting the command  `python StripCore.py` if it is not running, and killing it otherwise, you can use `psutil` to do this reliably.

Something like:

```
import psutil
from subprocess import Popen

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.cmdline() == ['python', 'StripCore.py']:
        print('Process found. Terminating it.')
        process.terminate()
        break
else:
    print('Process not found: starting it.')
    Popen(['python', 'StripCore.py'])
```

Sample run:

```
$python test_strip.py   #test_strip.py contains the code above
Process not found: starting it.
$python test_strip.py 
Process found. Terminating it.
$python test_strip.py 
Process not found: starting it.
$killall python
$python test_strip.py 
Process not found: starting it.
$python test_strip.py 
Process found. Terminating it.
$python test_strip.py 
Process not found: starting it.
```

---

**Note**: In previous `psutil` versions `cmdline` was an *attribute* instead of a method.

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem for me is how to get the pid of running application?

Comment: @Alex What do you mean? You'd like to terminate the process that is executing? Then simply use `sys.exit()`. If you want to access the `pid` of the current process use `os.getpid()`.

Comment: at_Bakuriu excuse me please (mi dispiace). I just want to make script which will run some app if it is not started. And if app is started, to terminate this app, and self too.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my question with a clean solution using `psutil`. If you want you can achieve this even using only the standard library but it will be less reliable(i.e. you save the pid to a file. A different process kills your `StripCore.py` script and starts a new process that gets assigned to the new pid: how can you know that the same pid now doesn't refer to the script running? This isn't a problem with psutil since you can check the `cmdline` attribute) and more complicated.

Comment: I think you mean `signal.SIGTERM`, not `signal.SIGQUIT`, sigquit is a keyboard emitted event.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the answer. Do you think this technique will also work on Mac OS-X, and specifically, if I need to "capture" a Mac application (which cannot run as a subprocess of the python-script) in order to terminate it?

Comment: @MottiShneor This should work on any OS supported by psutil, which include OS X, Windows, BSD, Solaris etc.

Comment: @AJP It's not due to the *python* version, but to the version of psutil. `cmdline` was an attribute in previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing as, but I wanted to do it in the one file.

So the logic would be:

- if a script with my name is running, kill it, then exit
- if a script with my name is not running, do stuff

I modified the answer by Bakuriu and came up with this:

```
from os import getpid
from sys import argv, exit
import psutil  ## pip install psutil

myname = argv[0]
mypid = getpid()
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.pid != mypid:
        for path in process.cmdline():
            if myname in path:
                print "process found"
                process.terminate()
                exit()

## your program starts here...
```

Running the script will do whatever the script does. Running another instance of the script will kill any existing instance of the script.

I use this to display a little PyGTK calendar widget which runs when I click the clock. If I click and the calendar is not up, the calendar displays. If the calendar is running and I click the clock, the calendar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

So, not directly related but this is the first question that appears when you try to find how to terminate a process running from a specific folder using Python.

It also answers the question in a way(even though it is an old one with lots of answers).

While creating a faster way to scrape some government sites for data I had an issue where if any of the processes in the pool got stuck they would be skipped but still take up memory from my computer. This is the solution I reached for killing them, if anyone knows a better way to do it please let me know!

```
import pandas as pd
import wmi
from re import escape
import os

def kill_process(kill_path, execs):
    f = wmi.WMI()
    esc = escape(kill_path)
    temp = {'id':[], 'path':[], 'name':[]}
    for process in f.Win32_Process():
        temp['id'].append(process.ProcessId)
        temp['path'].append(process.ExecutablePath)
        temp['name'].append(process.Name)
    temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
    temp = temp.dropna(subset=['path']).reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
    temp = temp.loc[temp['path'].str.contains(esc)].loc[temp.name.isin(execs)].reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
    [os.system('taskkill /PID {} /f'.format(t)) for t in temp['id']]
```