# Is there an way to start a python script and keep it running as process until user says stop explicitly

Tags: python-2.7

I am looking something like this.
If i have a method in a class, now that i accept 2 command line arguments (start, stop), so when i run python `script.py` start, it will start automatically, now after sometime if user enters `script.py stop` it should end gracefully, can it be done.

This is what i have tried to do

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
import sys

def start(name):
    print('hello', name)
    print "Sleeping for 60 sec"
    # sleep (60)



if __name__ == '__main__':


p = Process(target=start, args=('bob',))
p.start()
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks similar, is this what you want? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid