# Daemon thread launching software won't die

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a small script which will use plink.exe (from the same folder) to create a ssh tunnel (on windows).
I'm basically using `os.system` to launch the the command:

```
import time
import threading
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
pc_tunnel_command = '-ssh -batch -pw xxxx -N -L 1234:host1:5678 user@host2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target = os.system, \
                         args = (join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'plink.exe ') + \
                                      pc_tunnel_command,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    #without this line it will die. I guess that plink doesn't have enough time to start.
    time.sleep(5) 
    print 'Should die now'
```

However, it seems that the thread (and plink.exe) keep running. Why is this happening? Any way to force the thread to close?  Better way to launch plink?

I want plink.exe to die when my program ends. Using a daemon thread was my plan of having the tunnel run in the background, and then dying when my main code exits.

BTW - same thing happens with `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) and [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) modules to register calls back that will explicitly kill the process when your program exits normally or receives `SIGTERM`, respectively:

```
import sys
import time
import atexit
import signal
import subprocess
from functools import partial
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

pc_tunnel_command = '-ssh -batch -pw xxxx -N -L 1234:host1:5678 user@host2'


def handle_exit(p, *args):
    print("killing it")
    p.terminate()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = subprocess.Popen(join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'plink.exe ') + pc_tunnel_command, shell=True)
    func = partial(handle_exit, p)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, func)
    atexit.register(func)
    print 'Should die now'
```

The one thing that is odd about the behavior your desrcibed is that I would have expected your program to exit after your `sleep` call, but leave plink running in the background, rather than having your program hang until the `os.system` call completes. That's the behavior I see on Linux, at least. In any case, explicitly terminating the child process should solve the issue for you.

Comment: It works wonderfully. Thanks. A couple of questions, if I may: 1. Why is the call for `sys.exit(0)` necessary at the end of `handle_exit`? 2. why do you need the `partial` part? (It seems to be working w/o them)

Comment: @Korem when you use `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, ...)`your program will swallow the SIGTERM and call your handler. So if you don't explicitly tell your program to exit in the handler, it will keep running after handling the `SIGTERM`. In this case you want to exit when you receive the `SIGTERM`, but just clean up first. `partial` is used so that we can pass the `Popen` object to the `handle_exit`. The `signal.signal` API doesn't provide a way to pass arguments to the callback function you provide; using `partial` lets use work around that.

Comment: Oh, I wrote my comment before your recent edit, and at that time the `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, func)` line was commented out. It seemed to be working without it. Why do you use both?

Comment: @Korem `atexit` will run if your program exits normally, but it won't run if it gets terminated by a signal (like `SIGTERM`). On Windows I think this would probably only happen if someone used the task manager to end the process. Using `signal.signal` allows us to handle that case and still clean up properly.

Comment: @Korem Also note that `atexit.register` can take arguments for the callback function, so you could use `atexit.register(handle_exit, p)`. It's just `signal.signal` that needs `partial`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` does not return until the child process exits. The same is true for `subprocess.call`. That's why your thread is sitting there, waiting for plink to finish. You can probably use `subprocess.Popen` to launch the process asynchronously and then exit. In any case, the additional thread you are creating is unnecessary.

Comment: I disagree, and think that you perhaps misunderstand me. I *want* plink.exe to die when my program ends. Using a daemon thread was my plan of having the tunnel run in the background, and then dying when my main code exits. I would've imagined that the daemon thread gets some sort of "kill" signal, and thus the `os.system` call would be abruptly stopped. I knew that it won't return until it exits. And BTW, using Popen hangs as well.

Comment: @Korem you probably need to kill the process explicitly then, see  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid).