# Python: Send Signal to Process via PID File

Tags: python, pid, kill-process

A similar question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid), but my question is very specific: I don't have a PID, but a PID *file*. Is there a cleaner way of doing this other than reading the file myself? Preferably without an extra module to install.

To avoid an XY problem, what I really want to do is to issue this in Python: `pkill -HUP rsyslogd`. I am asking because I thought of `os.kill(pid_file, signal.SIGHUP)`, but if there is a different idea for doing what I want, that's more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The PID file just contains only the PID? This should work:

```
 pid = int(open(PID_FILE).read())
```

Comment: Thanks, that I know. I wanted to see if there is a better way (in other words, a built-in function that handles this and takes care of all what can go wrong while doing a file operation, possibly handling retries for example, since this is quite a common scenario). What you wrote will fail if the file operation fails and you have to handle the retries yourself.