# Closing a running program from a process

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, easygui

How can I close a program from a child process?
For exanple:

```
import easygui
import multiprocessing

def func():
    reply=easygui.buttonbox("start?",image="F:\project\phonber.png",choices=['yes','no'])
    if reply=="yes":
        exit_option()


if __name__=='__main__':
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=())
    t=p.start()
    while True:
        None
```

Is there a way to execute the `exit_option()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot to actually call the function:

```
import easygui
import multiprocessing

def func():
    reply=easygui.buttonbox("start?",image="F:\project\phonber.png",choices=['yes','no'])
    if reply=="yes":
        exit_option()

func()


if __name__=='__main__':
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=())
    t=p.start()
    while True:
        None
```

Then, to actually kill a running process there are, of course, many options. The most obvious ones being `psutil` its `kill` or `terminate` method, or `os` its kill method. Both as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114/4041795).