# Getting Python to kill a pid

Tags: python, python-2.7, pid

This is the current code I have right now and I'm wondering how I can get it to kill the pid.

```
import commands, signal
stuid = commands.getoutput("pgrep student")
deaid = commands.getoutput("pgrep daemon")
print stuid
os.kill(stuid, signal.SIGKILL)
print deaid
os.kill(deaid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Edit:
So, in the end, I just used os.system to get the terminal to run the kill command then place the pid after kill.

```
import commands, os
stuid = commands.getoutput("pgrep student")
deaid = commands.getoutput("pgrep daemon")
print stuid
os.system("kill "+stuid)
print deaid
os.system("kill "+deaid)
```

Overall this is my end result. Hope this helps people in the future.

Comment: There's probably some way to do this natively, but you could use a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: What about [psutil.Process](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process)?

Comment: you are on windows?

Comment: @DRPK No, i'm on a mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114/3090206).

BTW a more pythonic solution may be this:

```
    import re
    import psutil

    convicted = re.compile(r'student|daemon')

    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if convicted.search(p.name):
            p.terminate()
```

Edit: To be more accurate I changed the line `p.kill()` to `p.terminate()`. The common `kill` in bash is actually the same as `p.terminate()` (it sends the TERM signal). But the `p.kill()` corresponds to `kill -9` in bash (it sends the KILL signal).