# How can I stop Django server via command in cmd without click "CTRL + C"?

Tags: python, django, cmd

I'm writing my desktop app on PySide2 (it's not important) for control Django project (run server and stop server on buttons). I realized only start server, but I can't add stop server, because stop server is click on buttons `"CTRL + C"` in cmd and I don't now how to interpret clicks on buttons into code or any answers for this question.

Here is an example for "RUN server" and I need some help for "STOP server"

```
os.chdir(ui.lineEdit.text())   # Change directory
os.system("python manage.py runserver")   # Run server in this
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is something a terminal interprets. It will send a `SIGINT` signal to the process that is running. So it is not the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> itself that terminates the application.

You can do the same, for example by first opening a process with [**`Popen(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and then eventually send a signal:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from signal import SIGINT

# start the process
p = Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'])

# now stop the process
p.send_signal(SIGINT)
p.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer help me partially (For the start server), but I tried to stop server by your method and failed.But I found a solution: stop server through killing task from task manager.

Comment: @SashaZuev: then usually that means the process is "zombied". You can use a `SIGTERM` as well, but usually killing a process is not a good idea at all.

Comment: okey, I will consider this. Don't be surprised with my decisions - I recently started programming))

Comment: using `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)` load existing process by pid, [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114/2268680)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method that you could call from Python's `system`... this is also handy to make an alias to kill existing `runserver` processes for the current user (in case they get stuck):

```
# Kill any Django runserver instances for the current user
alias kill-runserver="ps -eaf | grep 'manage.py runserver' | grep "'$USER'" | grep -v grep | awk '{print "'$2'"}' | xargs kill -9"
```

After creating the alias, just run `kill-runserver`. If you want to be a little bit safer, eliminate the `-9` from the `kill` command.