# Running games using functions

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading

**My Code:**

```
import threading
import time 
import subprocess
Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Run_exe)

def run_exe():
    subproccess.call("game.exe")

while True:
   time.sleep(3600)
   x = int(input(""))
   if x==1:
      Thread1.start()
   else:
      Thread1.join()
```

My objective is the following:

- Run the game using the Run_exe function
- Kill thread when I exit the game

I don't want to exit game from the game itself
the Python program should get an input to exit the games by killing the thread.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes how run the game with python and exit it with python also without interfering with the games using functions and threads

Comment: Why are you using a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor and save the pid:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("game.exe")
pid = process.pid
```

If you want to stop the process, call: (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114/8733066))

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL
```