# Killing children of children in python with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, kill

Does python provide a way to find the children of a child process spawned using subprocess, so that I can kill them properly? If not, what is a good way of ensuring that the children of a child are killed?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of this (as it simply says don't invoke the shell. I'm looking for a way to get the children of spawned subprocess, the python spawned process is already being invoked directly) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638909/killing-a-subprocess-including-its-children-from-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly easy, but if your application runs in Linux, you could walk through the /proc filesystem and build a list of all PIDs whose PPID (parent PID) is the same as your subprocess'.

Comment: Sigh. So I take it the answer is effectively no. Thank you. I'll see if I can avoid subprocess spawns (or get them killed automatically).

Answer (score 5):

The following applies to Unix only:

Calling [os.setsid()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/setsid.html) in the child process will make it the session leader of a new session and the process group leader of a new [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). Sending a SIGTERM to the process group will send a SIGTERM to all the subprocess that this child process might have spawned.

You could do this using `subprocess.Popen(..., preexec_fn=os.setsid)`. For example:

```
import signal
import os
import subprocess
import time
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls -laR /', shell=True,
                        preexec_fn=os.setsid,
                        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
time.sleep(2)
os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Running this will show no output, but `ps ax` will show the subprocess and the `ls -laR` that it spawns are terminated.

But if you comment out

```
preexec_fn=os.setsid
```

then `ps ax` will show something like

```
% ps ax | grep "ls -la"
 5409 pts/3    S      0:00 /bin/sh -c ls -laR /
 5410 pts/3    R      0:05 ls -laR /
```

So without `os.setsid`, `ls -laR` and the shell that spawned it are still running. Be sure to kill them:

```
% kill 5409
% kill 5410
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot with killing a subprocess that spawned its own processes.