# Properly run and kill background process in a python script/pytest

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest, kill, portforwarding

I am writing some unit tests for a python program that requires the background execution of a port-forwarding command to query a service.

The program is a Kubernetes operator written in python using [Kopf](https://kopf.readthedocs.io/), thus I'm using pytest. The operator regularly queries the ingress controller metrics server. When ran within the cluster, it has access to the service. However unit tests are ran from outside so they require the following command to run in the background

```
kubectl port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 -n ingress-nginx
```

I browsed a bit of documentation, implemented a solution using `subprocess.Popen`, and wrote a nice decorator:

```
CMD = ['kubectl', 'port-forward', 'svc/metrics', '10254:80', '-n', 'ingress-nginx']
def expose_metrics_server(func):
    def wrapper():
        with subprocess.Popen(CMD, shell=False) as proc:
            func()
            proc.terminate()
    return wrapper
```

So far so good, right ?
However, my unit tests that assessed error handling when the metrics server is not up were failing.

I investigated and noticed the following behavior

- before `proc.terminate()`

```
(venv) user@debian:~/$ ps aux | grep kubectl
user    182770  0.0  0.0   6932  3348 ?        Ss   14:49   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/kubectl port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 -n ingress-nginx
user    182774  0.5  0.3 1809452 58680 ?       Sl   14:49   0:00 minikube kubectl -- port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 -n ingress-nginx
user    182816  1.1  0.2 762652 42432 ?        Sl   14:49   0:00 /home/user/.minikube/cache/linux/amd64/v1.27.4/kubectl port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 --cluster=minikube -n ingress-nginx
user    183312  0.0  0.0   6332  2044 pts/4    S+   14:49   0:00 grep kubectl
```

- after `proc.terminate()`

```
(venv) user@debian:~/$ ps aux | grep kubectl
user    182770  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   14:49   0:00 [kubectl] <defunct>
user    182774  0.1  0.3 1809452 58680 ?       Sl   14:49   0:00 minikube kubectl -- port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 -n ingress-nginx
user    182816  0.2  0.2 762652 42432 ?        Sl   14:49   0:00 /home/user/.minikube/cache/linux/amd64/v1.27.4/kubectl port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 --cluster=minikube -n ingress-nginx
user    183732  0.0  0.0   6332  2108 pts/4    S+   14:50   0:00 grep kubectl
```

- after test exited

```
(venv) user@debian:~/$ ps aux | grep kubectl
user    182774  0.1  0.3 1809452 58680 ?       Sl   14:49   0:00 minikube kubectl -- port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 -n ingress-nginx
user    182816  0.2  0.2 762652 42432 ?        Sl   14:49   0:00 /home/user/.minikube/cache/linux/amd64/v1.27.4/kubectl port-forward svc/metrics 10254:80 --cluster=minikube -n ingress-nginx
user    183793  0.0  0.0   6332  2152 pts/4    S+   14:50   0:00 grep kubectl
```

So basically the top process is being terminated but not its children. Which according to my research is way less trivial than it sounds.

So I tried various solutions like `preexec_fn=os.setsid`/`start_new_session=True` flags in the `Popen` command, or killing through various combination of tools provided by `os` and `signals` libraries. E.g. naive `os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)` or the more refined `os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc.pid), signal.SIGTERM)`. Running it through `os.fork` or `threadding.Thread`.

Most of those attempts did not changed anything, some resulted in infinite pending during deletion and I even managed to kill my X server once. I initially had set `Shell=True`, and setting it to false did not helped with termination, but removed `/bin/sh -c` top call.

Some recommend to use `psutil` but I'd like to stick with python base modules if possible.

#### "Working solution"

In the end I obtained the desired behavior through the sid + calling another shell to terminate since there's no `os.killsession` method

```
    with Popen(CMD, shell=False, start_new_session=True) as proc:
        func()
        call(['pkill', '-9', '-s', str(os.getsid(proc.pid))])
```

However, calling `pkill -9` like that sounds rather extreme and I have the intuition there should be a cleaner way to do this.
So I'm making this post to know if there are recommended patterns to run a shell command in the background alongside a python script then properly terminate it with all its children.

Thank you in advance for all input or hindsight.

Comment: This answer might help -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582602/13261176